# Connect QWizard.NextButton to custom method only on the first page

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qwizard, qwizardpage

I have a three pages wizard. First page is `BasicSettings()`, second page is `InstallPackages()` and the last page is `Summary()`.

I want the *Next* button on the first page to first execute a method named `execute_venv_create()` and then call the next page. On the following pages, the *Next* button should behave as usual.

For this I connected the *Next* button to `execute_venv_create()` like this:

```python
class VenvWizard(QWizard):
    """The wizard class."""
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # ...

class BasicSettings(QWizardPage):
    """This is the first page."""
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # ...

    def initializePage(self):
        next_button = self.wizard().button(QWizard.NextButton)
        next_button.clicked.connect(self.execute_venv_create)

    def execute_venv_create(self):
        # do something, then display an info message
        QMessageBox.information(self, "Done", "message text")
```

The problem is that of course the method is called every time I click *Next* and therefore I tried to disconnect the button and reconnect it to the `QWizard.next()` method in this way:

```python
class InstallPackages(QWizardPage):
    """This is the second page."""
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # ...

    def initializePage(self):
        next_button = self.wizard().button(QWizard.NextButton)
        next_button.disconnect()
        next_button.clicked.connect(QWizard.next)
```

On the first page the *Next* button works as I expect, it calls the method and switches to the next page. But then, on the second page `InstallPackages()`, the GUI crashes if I click *Next*.

---

Is this the right way to connect a `QWizard` button to a custom method or is it not possible to use wizard buttons from `QWizardPages`?

How to connect the `QWizard.NextButton` to a custom method of a specific `QWizardPage` and make the button behave as usual on the following pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is correct but you have to use the [QWizard](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwizard.html) object associated with the page that can be obtained through the [`wizard()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwizardpage.html#wizard) method:

```py
def execute_venv_create(self):
    # do something, then display an info message
    QMessageBox.information(self, "Done", "message text")
    next_button = self.wizard().button(QWizard.NextButton)
    next_button.disconnect()
    next_button.clicked.connect(self.wizard().next)
```